# How to display geojson data with meters on javascript google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mapbox, geojson

GeoJson file coordinates are in [X, Y] meters not in [lng, lat]. How to display it on google map?

> GeoJson data

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                360590,
                555610
              ],
              [
                360590,
                555555.0128
              ],
              [
                360590,
                555540
              ],
              [
                360592.4439,
                555540
              ],
              [
                360600,
                555540
              ],
              [
                360600,
                555518.8277
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

here, [360590, 555610] - [X, Y] coordinates is in meters, Now we need to display this coordinates on google map, Is there any solution for this?

also we must have to use addGeoJson or loadGeoJson method because we have 200MB data in GeoJson file.

Comment: Sounds like the data is in a different projection (perhaps EPSG:3857).  If that is true you need to reproject the points into EPSG:4326 (if it isn't true, you still need to get the equivalent WGS84/ESPG:4326 points).

Comment: yes @geocodezip may be that happens, but i need code snippet to resolve this issue, i found many solutions but neither was worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GeoJson features coordinates are in meters not in (lng, lat). How to display in google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508865/geojson-features-coordinates-are-in-meters-not-in-lng-lat-how-to-display-in)

Comment: After long Research I found that I am getting points in EPSG:27700. now need java code to transform individual points in WGS84/ESPG:4326 points.

Comment: i found solution on http://ageeksnotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/convert-easting-northing-to-latitude.html but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Converting in the backend would be better but there's a JS way too -- using [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) and [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=4326&x=1.0000000&y=2.0000000) to find the corresponding datums.

**Important point: the first and last positions of the linear ring need to be identical. Otherwise your GeoJSON is [not valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6).** So notice how my `points` array starts and ends w/ the same point.

---

After installing / importing `proj4js`:

```
// from https://epsg.io/27700
const EPSG_27700_DATUM = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs";

// from https://epsg.io/4326
const WGS84_DATUM = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

const points = [[360590,555610],[360590,555555.0128],[360590,555540],[360592.4439,555540],[360600,555540],[360600,555518.8277],[360590,555610]];

const converted_points = points.map(([lon, lat]) => {
    return proj4(EPSG_27700_DATUM, WGS84_DATUM, [lon, lat]);
});

console.info({ converted_points });
```

Validating that your polygon is indeed inside of GB:

[image]